# Multiple agent problem

Tags: java, multithreading

say you have multiple agents(**each of them is it's own process**) which can communicate to each other(agents communicate only in pairs); how do you ensure that once two agents start communicating, no other agent can interrupt them?

Here's the important part of the code:

```
class Agent {
    private void send(int to, byte[] message) {...};
    private void receive(int from, byte[] message) {...};
}
```

The send method sends the message to the specified agent and receive method processes the received message, that comes from other agents. So let's say agents with id=1 and id=2 exchange a few messages: how do I ensure that neither of the agents processes(in it's receive method) messages from any other agent during their exchange? I tried filtering messages based on agent's id(by storing them in int variable) but it doesn't seems to work properly?

Comment: Own process or own thread? Read [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html) if you are unsure.

Comment: @Ishtar: good point, I assumed threads in my answer...

Comment: So @ark, are the agent processes multithreaded or not?

Comment: @Ishtar: they're processes, not threads

Comment: I think we need to know more about the implementation of send() and receive() to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

With processes and using TCP for the IPC, at any time let every agent have at most one socket open. Then a second agent will never be able to talk with an already talking agent.

Answer (score 0):

You can give receivers a token.  When an agent want to send to a receiver, it should get the receiver's token at first.  After finishing the whole communication, the sender will release the token, and then other's can send to the receiver.